# Proof: function is discontinuous (via Limit-Criterion!)

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, continuity

I'd like to show that the function,

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \not\in \mathbb{Q}\\ 1 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$

is discontinuous via using the sequence-limit-criterion:

And I'd like to show:

"There is a sequence $(a_n)$ that contains only rational numbers and converges to $x_0$. Now $f(a_n) = 1$ but $f(a_n)−>f(x_0)=0$ is not possible$

I wonder which $" (a_n) "$ this could be. Which sequence can be chosen?

Comment: It really depends on what $x_0$ is. For instance, if $x_0=e$, then you can choose $a_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$, which converges to e.

Answer (score 1):

Choose for example

$$x_0:=3\;,\;x_1:=3.1\;,\;....,x_n=3.141592...a_n\;,\;a_n:=\text{the n-th decimal digit of }\;\;\pi$$

Now, the above isn't very nice since one usually does *not* know what that $\,a_n\,$ is, in particular for big values of $\,n\,$, yet it is possible to calculate as many digits of $\,\pi\,$ by means fo power series, say.

**Added:** An easier and nicer example can be given the other way around: choose the irrational sequence

$$\left\{\;a_n:=\frac{\pi n+1}{\pi n}\;\right\}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\frac 1n\lfloor nx_0\rfloor$ (where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes "greatest integer $\le x$"). Then $\mathbb Q\ni a_n\to x_0$. If $x_0$ is irrational, this shows that $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$.
If $x_0$ is rational, consider $a_n=\frac 1n\lfloor n(x_0-\sqrt 2)\rfloor+\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Thank's a lot! All of you are so fast.. I love this website :) Great!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $k_n$ be the largest integer such that $k_n^2<n^2$.  Then $\dfrac {k_n}n\to\sqrt 2$ as $n\to\infty$.